# unable to mount sd card from sony camera to ubuntu 16.04.1 system

Tags: mount, sd-card

I have a Sony CyberShot DSC-H70 camera, with a SanDisk 128 GB Extreme SD card. After taking 50 or so pictures, I decided to mount the card onto my Toshiba Satellite C655 running Ubuntu 16.04.1, but got the following error message. Is there anything that I can add to the system to make it able to mount? Thanks, in advance...

```
Error mounting /dev/sdb1 at /media/skline47/disk: 
Command-line `mount -t "exfat" -o "uhelper=udisks2,nodev,nosuid,uid=1000,gid=1000,iocharset=utf8,namecase=0,errors=remount-ro,umask=0077" "/dev/sdb1" "/media/skline47/disk"' 
exited with non-zero exit status 32: mount: unknown filesystem type 'exfat'
```

Answer (score 7):

To gain access to your sd card, just install the exFAT drivers (not installed by default):

```
sudo apt-get install exfat-fuse exfat-utils
```

Comment: This also helped in Ubuntu 18.04 to mount Sony a7.